# Why is code formatting broken in this Stack Overflow question?

Tags: bug, code-formatting

Consider this Stack Overflow question:

*[how to deserialize a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078480/how-to-deserialize-a-file)*

The code under bullet 1 seems to be formatted correctly, but something is confusing it and not rendering it as monospace text, respecting CRLFs, etc...